# How to extract text contents without markup tags from a html page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I want to extract only text from a html page excluding the markups. How can I achieve this in python(preferably) or java script?

For the following code:

```
<div id = #one>
 OneDivision
 <div id = #two>TwoDivision</div>
 <span>SpanElement</span>
</div>
```

My output should be:
OneDivision TwoDivision SpanElement

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ can do the job pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

It's super easy! From Javascript, use `textContent`. See the following code

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("one").textContent);
```

```html
<div id = "one">
 OneDivision
 <div id = "two">TwoDivision</div>
 <span>SpanElement</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<div id = #one>OneDivision<div id = #two>TwoDivision</div><span>SpanElement</span></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
print(soup.get_text(separator=' '))
```

---

**output**

```
'OneDivision TwoDivision SpanElement'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html_doc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').body

if html_doc is None:
    return None

for tag in html_doc.select('script'):
    tag.decompose()
for tag in html_doc.select('style'):
    tag.decompose()

text = html_doc.get_text(separator='\n')
```